# firefox's profile is inaccessible after system reinstallation

Tags: firefox

I reinstalled the system on the same partition, (home is on a different device) the version is the 14.04 LTS, unfortunately the Firefox profile is not loaded. How I can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox profile cannot be loaded after upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302891/firefox-profile-cannot-be-loaded-after-upgrade)

Comment: Is the error message "Missing Profile. Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible" or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: not sure this will work. It might overwrite the current profile. Best to make a backup of the old profile before attempting.

1. Run `firefox -P`
2. Click "Create profile". Follow the instructions.
3. When you get the option, click "choose folder" and select the location of the old profile. Finish the creation of the new profile.
4. Once you're back at the "Choose user profile" menu, select the one you just created and make sure "Use the selected profile without asking at startup" is selected, then click "Start Firefox".